# Was bedeutet „Ach wer wees, ach verwes“?

Tags: slang

Ich verstehe fast kein Wort da. In [mundmische](http://mundmische.de/bedeutung/31513-Ach_wer_wees_ach_verwes) finde ich eigentlich eine Erklärung, die aber selbst Umgangsprache ist:

> Schöner Spruch, wenn dir jemand auf die Eier geht.

Das Gespräch, das da zur Erklärung des Begriffes dient, ist folgendes:

> – Hast du schon gehört, dass Dortmund Herbstmeister ist? Was ist denn nur mit Bremen los?
>   – *Ach wer wees, ach verwes.*

Ich schätze, das sagt man, wenn man etwas überhaupt nicht leiden kann (pi mal Daumen). Ich benötigte aber eine genauere Erklärung folgender Wörter: *wees* und *verwes*.

(Soweit konnte ich nur *verwes* als vielleicht eine Konjugation des Verbs *verwesen* erkennen, bin aber nicht sicher.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"wees"* ist hier eine umgangssprachliche Verkürzung von *"weiß"*, volkommen richtig ist auch, dass *"verwes"* von *"verwesen"* ist.

Hier ist aber der umgangssprachliche Imperativ gegeben (Wegfall von *e* am Ende). 
Damit verbunden ist ein relativ einfacher Wortwitz (*"wer wees"* -> *"verwes"*)

Dadurch ergibt sich, beim Zurückbringen der Weggefallenen:

> Ach wer weiß, ach verwese.

Die Wendung drückt ein starkes Desinteresse am zuvor besprochenen Thema aus und gibt ein "sich-gestört-fühlen" des Sprechers wieder.